# What does the question mark and the colon (?: ternary operator) mean in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, c, syntax, operators, conditional-operator

What does this line of code mean?

```
label.frame = (inPseudoEditMode) ? kLabelIndentedRect : kLabelRect;
```

The `?` and `:` confuse me.

Comment: It's the ternary [*if-then-else*](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Operators_and_Expressions#The_Ternary_Operator) operator

Comment: Note that this should be question mark, not quotation mark.

Comment: The compiler also seems to allow `variable ?: anotherVariable`, what does this mean?'

Comment: The ternary with no first element means the same as `(valOrVar != 0) ? valOrVar : anotherValorvar`

Answer (score 455, accepted):

This is the C [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) (Objective-C is a superset of C):

```
label.frame = (inPseudoEditMode) ? kLabelIndentedRect : kLabelRect;
```

is semantically equivalent to

```
if(inPseudoEditMode) {
 label.frame = kLabelIndentedRect;
} else {
 label.frame = kLabelRect;
}
```

The ternary with no first element (e.g. `variable ?: anotherVariable`) means the same as `(valOrVar != 0) ? valOrVar : anotherValOrVar`

Comment: (update: Yuck! Reposting as an answer.)
What is so important about the ternary operator is that it can be used in places that an if-else cannot. ie: Inside a condition or method parameter.

[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Status: %@", (statusBool ? @"Approved" : @"Rejected")]

...which is a great use for preprocessor constants:

#define statusString (statusBool ? @"Approved" : @"Rejected")

...then:

[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Status: %@", statusString]

This saves you from having to use and release local variables in if-else patterns. FTW!

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the ternary operator without the first element (`?:`) is *even better* in situations in which the left side is an expression, as the `?:` prevents it from being evaluated more than once.  For example: `[myArray firstObject] ? [myArray firstObject] : @"Hello World";` calls `firstObject` twice (if `firstObject` does not return `nil`), where `[myArray firstObject] ?: @"Hello World";` produces the identical result but never calls `firstObject` more than once.

Comment: finally~~~~~ I have been using this operator for ages (defo my favourite) but never knew what it's called. the big question has now been answered. Thanks

Comment: Also want to add that the ternary operator without the first element `?:` is also called the [**Elvis operator**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator) due to the *emoji* resemblance to the singer. And of course in this case as we are dropping one element, it no longer is a *ternary operator* but a **binary operator**. Binary operators include the vast majority of the operators we usually use when programming (`*`,`+`,`-`,`^`, `|`,`||`, `&`, `>>`, etc).

Answer (score 189):

It's the ternary or conditional operator. It's basic form is:

```
condition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse
```

Where the values will only be evaluated if they are chosen.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's not limited to values. `condition ? codeIfTrue : codeIfFalse`

Comment: ... or, to use more precise language, all three operands are **expressions**. `condition_expression ? expression1 : expression2`. Expressions can be variables, function results, ... -  or combinations thereof.

Answer (score 68):

Simply, the logic would be

`(condition) ? {code for YES} : {code for NO}`

Comment: This is actually the **best** answer because the other answers imply that you can only have a "value" as a result, whereas this shows that you can put any arbitrary code as a result.

Answer (score 36):

Building on Barry Wark's excellent explanation...

What is so important about the ternary operator is that it can be used in places that an if-else cannot. ie: Inside a condition or method parameter.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Status: %@", (statusBool ? @"Approved" : @"Rejected")]
```

...which is a great use for preprocessor constants:

```
// in your pch file...
#define statusString (statusBool ? @"Approved" : @"Rejected")

// in your m file...
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Status: %@", statusString]
```

This saves you from having to use and release local variables in if-else patterns. FTW!

Answer (score 17):

That's just the usual [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).  If the part before the question mark is true, it evaluates and returns the part before the colon, otherwise it evaluates and returns the part after the colon.

```
a?b:c
```

is like

```
if(a)
    b;
else
    c;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is part of C, so it's not Objective-C specific.  Here's a translation into an `if` statement:

```
if (inPseudoEditMode)
    label.frame = kLabelIndentedRec;
else
    label.frame = kLabelRect;
```

Answer (score 4):

It's just a short form of writing an if-then-else statement. It means the same as the following code:

```
if(inPseudoEditMode)
  label.frame = kLabelIndentedRect;
else
  label.frame = kLabelRect;
```

Answer (score 3):

Fun fact, in objective-c if you want to check null / nil
For example:

```
-(NSString*) getSomeStringSafeCheck
{
    NSString *string = [self getSomeString];
    if(string != nil){
        return String;
    }
    return @"";
}
```

The quick way to do it is:

```
-(NSString*) getSomeStringSafeCheck
{
    return [self getSomeString] != nil ? [self getSomeString] : @"";
}
```

Then you can update it to a simplest way:

```
-(NSString*) getSomeStringSafeCheck
{
    return [self getSomeString]?: @"";
}
```

Because in Objective-C:

1. if an object is nil, it will return false as boolean;
2. Ternary Operator's second parameter can be empty, as it will return the result on the left of '?'

So let say you write:

```
[self getSomeString] != nil?: @"";
```

the second parameter is returning a boolean value, thus a exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

> Ternary operator example.If the value of isFemale
>   boolean variable is YES, print "GENDER IS FEMALE" otherwise "GENDER IS
>   MALE"

```
? means = execute the codes before the : if the condition is true. 
: means = execute the codes after the : if the condition is false.
```

Objective-C

> ```
> BOOL isFemale = YES;
> NSString *valueToPrint = (isFemale == YES) ? @"GENDER IS FEMALE" : @"GENDER IS MALE";
> NSLog(valueToPrint); //Result will be "GENDER IS FEMALE" because the value of isFemale was set to YES.
> ```

For Swift

> ```
> let isFemale = false
> let valueToPrint:String = (isFemale == true) ? "GENDER IS FEMALE" : "GENDER IS MALE"
> print(valueToPrint) //Result will be  "GENDER IS MALE" because the isFemale value was set to false.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It is ternary operator, like an if/else statement.

```
if(a > b) {
what to do;
}
else {
what to do;
}
```

In ternary operator it is like that: 
condition ? what to do if condition is true : what to do if it is false;

```
(a > b) ? what to do if true : what to do if false;
```

Comment: I appreciate that you're attempting to contribute to the site, but posting answers which simply repeat what other answers have already stated is generally discouraged, as it just clutters up questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
int padding = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height <= 480) ? 15 : 55;
```

means

```
int padding; 
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height <= 480)
  padding = 15;
else
  padding = 55;
```

Answer (score 1):

I just learned something new about the ternary operator. The short form that omits the middle operand is truly elegant, and is one of the many reasons that C remains relevant. FYI, I first really got my head around this in the context of a routine implemented in C#, which also supports the ternary operator. Since the ternary operator is in C, it stands to reason that it would be in other languages that are essentially extensions thereof (e. g., Objective-C, C#).

Answer (score 1):

As everyone referred that, It is a way of representing conditional operator

```
if (condition){ 
    true 
} 
else {
    false
}
```

using ternary operator `(condition)? true:false`
To add additional information, In swift we have new way of representing it using `??`.

```
let imageObject: UIImage = (UIImage(named: "ImageName")) ?? (initialOfUsername.capitalizedString).imageFromString
```

Which is similar to

```
int a = 6, c= 5;
if (a > c) 
{ 
 a is greater
} else {
 c is greater
}
```

is equivalent to

`if (a>c)?a:c` ==> Is equal to `if (a>c)?:c`

instead of `?:` we can use `??` is swift.