# Use of question mark ? when setting a variable

Tags: objective-c, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the question mark and the colon (?: ternary operator) mean in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595392/what-does-the-question-mark-and-the-colon-ternary-operator-mean-in-objectiv)

I understand that we're setting `oldRow` equal to some index path.  I have never seen this syntax and can't find explanation in the book I'm using.  What is the purpose of the `?` in the code below and what exactly does this code do?

```
int oldRow = (lastIndexPath != nil) ? [lastIndexPath row] : -1;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int oldRow = (lastIndexPath != nil) ? [lastIndexPath row] : -1;
```

is equivalent to:

```
int oldrow = 0;
if (lastIndexPath != nil)
    oldRow = [lastIndexPath row];
else 
    oldRow = -1;
```

That syntax is called a ternary operator and follows this syntax:

```
condition ? trueValue : falseValue;

i.e oldRow = (if lastIndexPath is not nil ? do this : if it isn't do this);
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks a lot.  I see this syntax popping up a lot recently, so this was really helpful.

Comment: FWIW the correct name is ternary, not tertiary.

Answer (score 2):

This is a shorthand if statement. Basically it is the same as:

```
int oldRow;

if(lastIndexPath != nil)
{
    oldRow = [lastIndexPath row];
}
else
{
     oldRow = -1;
}
```

It is very handy with conditional assignments

Answer (score 1):

this code is equal to this code

```
int oldRow;

if (lastIndexPath != nil)
   oldRow = [lastIndexPaht row];
else
   oldRow = -1;
```