# A weird return statement in C / Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, return

everyone,

I am new to C / Objective-C and I am doing some exercise in Xcode. Actually it was lecture two from Stanford iTunes.U CS 193 iOS course fall 2013, if somebody's familiar with...

The exercise was asking to create a property for a class called Card.

So in .h file it declares:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *suit;
```

And in .m file it overrode the getter method:

```
-(NSString *)suit
{
    return _suit ? _suit : @"?";
}
```

Here it is, I don't understand what this return statement means...

According to the instructor, the getter method prevents the suit property being nil. But I tried to use the following code instead of the code above, it didn't work.

```
-(NSString *)suit
{
    if (!_suit)
        return _suit;
    else
        return @"?";
}
```

So two questions here:

1,

`return _suit ? _suit : @"?";`

what does this return statement mean?

2, Why my code did not work?

Appreciated!

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216384/boolean-operation-syntax

Answer (score 2):

The `x ? y : z` syntax is called the [conditional or ternary if operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a). If `x` is true, its value is `y`, otherwise its value is `z`.

When you converted it into the `if`/`else` form, you inverted `_suit`, when you shouldn't have. It should read:

```
if (_suit)
    return _suit;
...
```

Comment: It is called *conditional* operator.

Comment: That was clear. Thanks a million!

Comment: @MartinR Since it's the only ternary operator in C, I usually just hear it called the ternary operator. I don't think I've ever actually heard it called by something useful like the conditional operator, but that does make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

change your code to as followings:

```
-(NSString *)suit
{
    if (_suit) //if _suit exists, then return _suit. !_suit is wrong.
        return _suit;
    else
        return @"?";
}
```