# Javascript selectors in variables?

Tags: javascript, variables

I have been reviewing other peoples javascript codes and noticed variable lines like this:

`opacity = isIn ? 0 : 1;`,

`opacity = isIn ? opacity + gap : opacity - gap;`,

`var s = this == binary ? h(binary, f, change, text) : h(text, r, change2, binary);`,

And other lines of code like that. How do they work? What type of variable are they?

Thank you so much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the question mark and the colon (?: ternary operator) mean in objective-c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595392/what-does-the-question-mark-and-the-colon-ternary-operator-mean-in-objectiv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a special form of `if` called a conditional (or ternary) operator:

```
var value = condition ? value_when_true : value_when_false;
```

If the `condition` evaluates to `true`, `value` will be assigned `value_when_true`, if not, `value_when_false`.

It is functionally the same as:

```
var value;
if (condition) {
  value = value_when_true;
} else {
  value = value_when_false;
}
```

See [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for detailed description.

Comment: @CodeApprentice remember that just like in an `if`, `value_when_true` and `value_when_false` can be any expression you want evaluated, as long as the interpreter doesn't encounter a line delimiter `;` (using `,` instead tends to be okay). You may want to use parenthesis if doing multiple `?:`s and if it starts to look complicated, it's usually easier for everyone if you switch to a normal `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Its called ternary operators

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

```
var s = (some_condition) ? if_true_value : if_false_value;
```

same as

```
if(some_condition){
   s = if_true_value;
}else{
   s = if_false_value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was also helpful.