# what does this return statement mean

Tags: c, ternary-operator, conditional-operator, return

In the book these is a simple C function:

```
char *month_name(int n)
{
  static char *name[] = {
  "Illegal month",
  "January", "February", "March",
  "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September",
  "October", "November", "December"
  };

  return (n < 1 || n > 12) ? name[0] : name[n];
}
```

What does this function do is easy to understand, but I don't understand the return statement, how does this return statement work here.

Comment: Which part don't you understand? The `? :` operator?

Comment: What in that statement do you not understand?

Comment: The `?:` is called the **conditional operator**. Many people *(wrongly)* call it the **ternary operator** because it is composed of 3 sub-expressions; but the C Standard does not have that name in it anywhere.

Comment: @pmg: *The ternary operator* is correct (the definite particle is important there): It is the only ternary operator in the language. The fact that it is the *conditional operator* does not make it wrong.

Comment: @Deduplicator: that's why i put wrongly between parenthesis and italicized. Anyway, I prefer to call it the conditional operator so that when a new ternary operator is introduced to the language I don't have to switch gears :)

Comment: That's a very verbose way of writing it. Shorter would be: `return name[n < 1 || n > 12 ? 0 : n];`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the question mark and the colon (?: ternary operator) mean in objective-c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595392/what-does-the-question-mark-and-the-colon-ternary-operator-mean-in-objectiv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a ternary operator..

```
condition? a: b
```

this means if condition is true then expression a wil be processed, if its false then b will be processed.

In your code, it will check if n is not within the range 1-12 (the number of months). if it is not within the range then it will return name[0] (i.e. illegal month). else if it is within the range then it will print the name of the month using n as the index of the array name.

Answer (score 2):

`return (n < 1 || n > 12) ? name[0] : name[n];` could be rewritten as:

```
if (n < 1 || n > 12)
    return name[0];
else
    return name[n];
```

So function returns name of month for n = 1...12 passed to function, otherwise it returns "illegal month".

Answer (score 1):

`? :` is ternary operator.

If `n < 1 || n > 12` it will return `"Illegal month"` else name of the month.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a *ternary operator*, and it means: if n < 1 or n > 12, return `name[0]` - "Illegal month". Else, return `name[n]` - the proper month.

Answer (score 1):

It's equivalent to the following:

```
if(n < 1 || n > 12)
    return name[0];
else
    return name[n];
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanded, that return statement is equivalent to this:

```
if (n < 1 || n > 12)
{
    return name[0];
}
else
{
    return name[n];
}
```

The return statement employs a *ternary operation* which has the following syntax:

```
(if condition)? true_return_value: false_return_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

While many have pointed out that this is the same as:

```
if(n < 1 || n > 12)
    return name[0];
else
    return name[n];
```

that's not exactly true. The ternary operator is an *operator*, so that `(n < 1 || n > 12) ? name[0] : name[n]` is an *expression*, not a statement.  A closer example would be:

```
string ret_value;

if(n < 1 || n > 12)
    ret_value = name[0];
else
    ret_value =name[n];

return ret_value;
```

This becomes important when you need the conditional in the middle of things:

```
 return String.Format("The test {0} successful", bOK ? "WAS" : "was NOT");
```