# Swift ?? objc alternative

Tags: objective-c

Does ObjC have something like in swift default value?

```
let a = b.name ?? "Empty"
```

I have an object with parameters and I have to check all parameters if they are not nil and if yes, set them to some default value.

Comment: In C (and therefore Objective-C) `nil` evaluates to `false` so you can use the standard ternary operator `NSString *a = b.name ? b.name:@"Empty"`

Comment: the ObjC alternative is `?:` for Swift `??`, like in your case that would look something like this in ObjC: `NSString *a = b.name ?: @"Empty";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Ternary operator in most of the programming language. You can find details on this here - [What does the question mark and the colon (?: ternary operator) mean in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595392/what-does-the-question-mark-and-the-colon-ternary-operator-mean-in-objectiv)

In Objective C ?? replaced by ?: Do follow the link or here is a short example if this comes to your help -

```
NSString *msgFullString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Message: %@", msg ? : @"Unknown error"];
```

You can also check if value exist or not using if(b.name). it will return true if b.name has a value or false if b.name is nil.

Hope this helps....

Comment: at least if you copied my comment to make an own answer, you could have spend a little more time to format it properly.

Comment: What is known by everyone, doesn't look like copy or stealing to me, anyone will answer like this given the swift code.

Comment: you __actually__ coped and pasted my comment word-by-word, apart from you have cut off the middle part... geez. at least be a bit more humble, if you are not able to come out the answer on your own.

Comment: geez, why are you making this a big issue or something ? i have said already -  What is known by everyone, doesn't look like copy or stealing to me & also another way for checking nil is also given. what's the problem here ?!!!

Comment: @holex sir, let's just be helpful we all, Here is ternary operators for you that everyone know :) 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Comment: the problem is you being painfully high-minded and arrogant while aggressively chasing score – and in spite of you'd format your answer (=the copy of my comment) properly you are spending more energy and time on to convince me about what is common knowledge and what is not. over and out.

Comment: i rarely comment in stackoverflow anyways and regarding score, you can check profile activity. I haven't even though about this before you have said this ! and i am being arrogant. Clap & adios.